# Emmet wrap with abbreviation empty lines

Tags: php, html, regex, emmet

Using emmet in sublime text 2, selecting empty lines and wrapping with abbreviation with this tr>td* removes empty lines. Any solution to prevent it to remove empty lines?
Selecting the lines below and wrapping with tr>td* should give 5 lines of td but it gives only 3.

```
12

34

56
```

Unwanted result:

```
    <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>56</td>
    </tr>
```

Wanted result:

```
    <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>56</td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it’s not possible: Emmet automatically removes empty lines to better deal with texts pasted from external document sources.

As a workaround, try to wrap your text into the following abbreviation:

`tr*>td{$#}+td`

E.g. use `$#` variable to explicitly point where to put wrapped content

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I need this for a table that has randomly empty columns. Column number is determined but column value. So empty columns must be kept.